# Using spring jdbc templates for db access in a plain servlets app

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

If I have a raw servlets application, how hard is it to integrate spring's jdbc templates into it?

I don't want to deal with the low level jdbc code, so I was thinking of using jdbc templates.

I'm not looking to use spring as a IOC or anything, just want to use the jdbc tooling to make db access a little less painful.

Does it have any dependencies or assume things to be in place other than the necessary jars?

I'm using tomcat's jdbc pool, so I have a datasource to pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

It is *very* simple to add and it does not require you use IOC.  If you use maven or ivy, the dependencies are handled for you otherwise it is likely you will need spring-core and possibly spring-beans (i dont know the specifics off the top of my head).  Also, if you want transactions, then you will want IOC as the container would create proxy beans that implement the transactional behavior.